# The Greatest Prime Less Than $n$

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

Let $n$ be any natural number greater than 2. Let $l$ be the greatest prime less than $n$. When $n$=3, $l$=2. When $n$=10, $l$=7. When $n$=25, $l$=23.

What is the relationship between $n$ and $l$? Can this relationship be expressed as a function?: $l$($n$)

\begin{align}
l(3) & = 2 \\
l(4) & = 3 \\
l(5) & = 3 \\
l(6) & = 5 \\
l(7) & = 5 \\
\end{align}

$l$(7)=5 means that the greatest prime less than 7 is 5. Are there any known ways to calculate $l$($n$)? Is it possible to make a formula to calculate $l$($n$)?

Comment: Of course there are ways to calculate $l(n)$, but they're not _useful_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is indeed a function, and can be calculated. (Indeed, most computer algebra systems include such a function, or one very similar; see for example [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)'s `precprime`.)

Bounds on the value of this function are pretty well-studied; I think the results of Baker-Harman-Pintz are state-of-the-art, showing that the gap is $O(n^{0.525}).$

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is a very hard problem, but take a look at 
[Prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: The prime counting function gives the number of prime numbers less than a given number. I am seeking to identify them.

Comment: I,m not sure but think that see some where $$ n\ln n < p_n < n\ln n + n$$ If it's helpful search prime number in wikipedia for exact relation.